# Simple upper bound on number of iterations of Euclidean algorithm

Tags: number-theory, euclidean-algorithm

This is from the book "An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers" by Niven, Zuckerman and Montgomery.

> The exact number of iterations $j$ of the Euclidean algorithm required to calculate $(b,c)$ depends in an intricate manner on $b$ and $c$, but it is easy to establish a rough bound for $j$ as follows:
> If $r_i$ is small compared to $r_{i-1}$ say $r_i\leq r_{i-1}/2$, then substantial progress has been made at this step. Otherwise $r_{i-1}/2<r_{i}<r_{i-1}$, in which case $q_{i+1}=1$ and $r_{i+1}=r_{i-1}-r_i<r_{i-1}/2$. This we see that $r_{i+1}<r_{i-1}/2$ in either case. From this it can be deduced that $j<3\log c$ ($\log$ is base $e$). With more care, we could improve on the constant $3$, but it is comparable to $\log c$, and so it is easy to compute $\textrm{gcd}$ easily, as $\log$ grows slowly.

What I don't understand is - how is it deduced that $j<3\log c$?

Answer (score 1):

The value of $c$ at least halves every two steps, and at worst needs to reach $1$, so the number of steps is less than $2 \log_2 c = 2 \log_2 e \log_e c < 3 \log_e c$.

Comment: why $j<2 \log_2 c$?

Comment: @diiiiiklllllll The books proof shows that $r_{i+1}<\frac{1}{2} r_{i-1}$; that is, every two iterations of the algorithm halve (or better) the value of $c$, which needs to reach $1$ for the algorithm to terminate. The number of halvings required is $\log_2 c$, and the factor of $2$ is because $c$ is only halves every two iterations, so the number of iterations might be as much as twice the maximum number of halvings..